# How to do Kafka Copartition join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am doing a ktable join between 2 kafka topics with different partition sizes (8 and 32). They both have same key. What’s the best way to do the join without creating an external topic of same partition sizes.

Thanks

Comment: I guess, the only way to do the join with Kafka Streams is with the additional topic.

Comment: Thanks Matthias. I just needed to confirm that.

Unfortunately, I do not have control over the source topics. Would be nice if the same could be achieved using internal topics.

Comment: That is hard... The problem is, that inserting internal topics happens at compile time -- but we don't know the number of partitions at compile time.